# jQuery: target first 3 of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements as follows:

```js
var locationSlug = "paris";
$('div a.country-item.' + locationSlug).slice(0, 3).show();
```

```css
.country-item { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <a class="country-item paris london">Text1</a>
  <a class="country-item tokyo london">Text2</a>
  <a class="country-item paris moscow">Text3</a>
  <a class="country-item berlin london">Text4</a>
  <a class="country-item paris madrid">Text5</a>
  <a class="country-item barcelona edinburgh">Text6</a>
  <a class="country-item nice dublin">Text7</a>
  <a class="country-item paris stockholm">Text8</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to show the first 3 instances of elements with `.paris` class, so not the first 3 children as the list is going to be quite long. I tried the following selector

```
$('div a.country-item.' + locationSlug).slice(0, 3).show();
```

but this slice method didn't seem to work at all.

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could just use regular javascript" `document.getElementsByClass('paris')` or retrieve the parent div first, and replace document with that parent element.

Comment: @JeremyE. but how would I select the first 3 instances of said class?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('paris').slice(0, 3).style.display = 'block';

Comment: My bad, it does not return an array but an array like object.

Comment: You either have to use a for loop in regular javascript, or the lt-selector in jquery as mentioned in the answer below. Since you're already using jquery, I think that's your best bet

Comment: _"but this slice method didn't seem to work at all."_ Cannot reproduce. `javascript` at Question appears to return expected result.

Answer (score 3):

use the jQuery `:lt() selector`

```
 var locationSlug="paris";
  $('div.parent a.'+locationSlug+':lt(3)').show();
```

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div > a").hide();
  var locationSlug="paris";
  $('div.parent a.'+locationSlug+':lt(3)').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <a class="country-item paris london">paris1</a>
    <a class="country-item tokyo london">Text</a>
    <a class="country-item paris moscow">paris2</a>
    <a class="country-item berlin london">Text</a>
    <a class="country-item paris madrid">paris3</a>
    <a class="country-item barcelona edinburgh">Text</a>
    <a class="country-item nice dublin">Text</a>
    <a class="country-item paris stockholm">paris4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is issue with `javascript` at Question?